# angularjs - form with ng-repeat inside it error on submitting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have the following form : two text inputs then an ng-repeat with a text and radio inside.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="myForm" name="myForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="cname" ng-model="company.name" class="form-control" required></input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">HQ</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select ng-model="company.hq" ng-options="hq as hq.name for hq in hqs" required>
                <option></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in getR(4) track by $index">
            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Top pick {{$index+1}}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="quizsize" ng-model="company.product[$index]" class="form-control" required></input>
                <label><input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="company.radioValue" value="{{$index+1}}"/> Choose</label>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit"  value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="addCompany(company)"></button>
            <button type="btn" value="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancelBtn()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

addCompany method from the controller :

```
$scope.addCompany = function(company)
    {
        console.log(company.radioValue);
        $http.post('http://localhost/api/index.php/Test/companies', company)
            .success(function(data)
        {
            $scope.companies.push(data[0]);
        })
        .error(function(err)
        {

        })
    };
```

And the method to for the inputs ng-repeat:

```
$scope.getR = function(n)
    {
        return Array(n);
    }
```

When I submit it:

If I start by adding company name/hq then all is good, but
If I start by first clicking on a radio button then when I send the form I get an undefined radioValue error.

Comment: Can you post the complete code or add a sample with JSFiddle?

Comment: I have added the complete form and add method from the controller. If I start filling the form by first adding a name,hq then that console.log(radiovalue) will display but if I start by choosing a radio button it will display undefined.

Answer (score 0):

use ng-value instead of value to be sure the model is ready to be bound to

```
<input type="radio" ng-value="($index + 1)" ng-model="company.radioValue">
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

Comment: you should still be using ng-value within an ng-repeat as per the docs oh and a typo in my answer I've corrected should have been $index of course